# Group by multiple enumerables in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 Lists containing entries of a custom class I have created. Basically, each lists contains a customers orders - but they come from 2 different sources, hence the 2 List's. Both list's are the same type however (my custom class), and there is a field to identify which customer the order belongs to.

What I want to do is make a new list, containing each customer that has an order in either of the lists, and the count of the orders from both lists. So, they'll be 3 fields: The customer's ID, the number of orders from list 1, and the number of orders from list 2.

I know there's many ways to do this, but all the ways I've thought of seem needlessly complex. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Can you describe some of the ways you've thought about doing this that you would classify as "needlessly complex"?  Just so that some of us don't waste our time writing something you already don't like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would be a good starting point for further tweaks:

```
var ordersInList1 = list1.GroupBy(order => order.CustomerId)
                         .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
var ordersInList2 = list2.GroupBy(order => order.CustomerId)
                         .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());

var results = ordersInList1.Keys.Union(ordersInList2.Keys)
                           .Select(id =>
                           new { 
                                CustomerId = id, 
                                CountOrders1 = ordersInList1[id], 
                                CountOrders2 = ordersInList2[id]
                           })
                           .ToArray();
```